# Position absolute messes up Bootstrap's breadcrumb in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, position

The issue is quite simple really. Here is my CSS:

```
.fixed-body {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="fixed-body">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="active">Name with spaces<span class="divider">/</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a><span class="divider">/</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Everything looks all right in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer 8. This is how it renders the Breadcrumb:

[image: IE8 rendering of the Bootstrap's breadcrumb]

You can see it for yourself in [this jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/amiramix/azm53/show/). This is just the resulting frame because jsfiddle doesn't render on IE8 properly. The whole fiddle is at [this address](http://jsfiddle.net/amiramix/azm53/) (it's the same address without the "show" part in the URL).

There are two reasons why it doesn't render properly:

1. The CSS directive `position: absolute` in `.fixed-body`
2. Spaces in the first section of the breadcrum `Name with spaces`

If the first section doesn't contain spaces or the `position` of the parent node isn't set to `absolute` then Internet Explorer 8 renders the breadcrumb properly.

I tried to wrap the breadcrumb in another `div` and reset its `position` to `static` but it doesn't help. Is there any specific limitation of Internet Explorer 8 that shows in that way? And most interestingly, is there any way of fixing or working around this problem?

**EDIT (copied from my response):**

Just found by accident the proper fix. Overriding `inline-block` with `inline` for `li` in the breadcrumb gives the desired effect without any side issues (AFAIK):

```
.breadcrumb > li {
    display: inline;
}
```

See also the new version of [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amiramix/azm53/14/), or open just the [show frame in IE8](http://fiddle.jshell.net/amiramix/azm53/14/show/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, setting the `display` to `inline-block` gives a similar result as the answer gave by ITChristian:

```
.breadcrumb {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

However, both solutions have some problems. In case of setting `width` to a fixed value the site ceases to be responsive (the breadcrumb will not size with the window). When setting `display` to `inline-block` the gray background shrinks to only cover the links, leaving a white strip to the right. If after setting `display` to `inline-block` the `width` is set to 100% then it overflows the right border (since the width is to take 100% of the parent's element). Maybe the simplest solution would be to just get rid of the spaces?

**EDIT:**

Just found by accident the proper fix. Overriding `inline-block` with `inline` for `li` in the breadcrumb gives the desired effect without any side issues (AFAIK):

```
.breadcrumb > li {
    display: inline;
}
```

See also the new version of [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amiramix/azm53/14/), or open just the [show frame in IE8](http://fiddle.jshell.net/amiramix/azm53/14/show/).

Comment: Thanks, fixed my exact same issue with IE8

Answer (score 2):

This is because of "breadcrumb" width...

Check this in IE8: http://fiddle.jshell.net/azm53/12/show

I have changed breadcrumb width to 400px and it's ok.

```
<div class="fixed-body">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="active">Name with spaces<span class="divider">/</span>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a><span class="divider">/</span>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Library</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.fixed-body {
    position: absolute;
}
.breadcrumb {
    width: 400px;
}
```